# Can I detect, if the request comes from cURL?

Tags: php, curl, nginx

I use NGINX. For personal reason, I want to detect if the request comes from cURL, then redirect to my static page (eg. mydomain.com/curl).

How to do that?
Where I should use that? (nginx.conf or can I do that in php script?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't.

At least if the request was launched by a competent person deliberately trying to look like a browser. If they're not trying to mislead you, just look at the user-agent.

OTOH you could use JavaScript to redirect real browsers.